# instance と object のニュアンスの違い

Tags: 英語, 専門用語

オブジェクト指向の話題でよく出てくる用語に object と instance の２つがあります。
日本語的にはどちらも class 型な変数の意味で用いられていることが多いように感じます。
でも単語も違いますし、ニュアンスは違いそうに思えます。

この2つの用語はどう違うのでしょうか？
（あるいはどう同じなのでしょうか？）

Comment: 自分もよく分からない内容だったので面白い題目だと思いました。本家でも結構同じ質問されているみたいですね。 http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what+is+the+difference+instance+object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yuki Inoueさんとそう違わない感覚だとは思いますが、

> オブジェクト指向のオブジェクトとはもう少し広い概念で...

オブジェクトをどうとらえているかはYuki Inoueさんと同じです。

> クラスベースではインスタンス=オブジェクトだが...

インスタンス＝実体という訳を自分は素朴に解釈していてプログラムからみてそれが「何か意味のある情報をカプセル化していてメッセージを送ると何かしてくれるようなものと理解しています。これは特定の言語システムの話をしているなら意味が違ってくると思います。例えばJavaなどではクラスも実体を持っていてプログラムからアクセスできるという意味でオブジェクト（かつインスタンスといっても御幣はない）と解釈しています。一方でC++のようなものだとC++クラスに対して実行時に何かアクセスするようなコードを普通書かない（書けない）ものだと思うのでC++クラスはインスタンスでもないしオブジェクトでもないと思います。

特定の言語システムの話をしているのではない文脈では、クラスとインスタンスという用語を、「振る舞いの定義」と「定義に従って振る舞う個々の実体」として明確に区別したい場合に使い、特に区別する必要がないような文脈では先の定義通りの意味でオブジェクトという用語を使っていると思います。

Comment: チェックマークをどちらに付けるか悩んだのですが、使う文脈の違いに関してわかりやすかったので KSOH さんのほうにチェック。 Yuki Inoue さんの解説も大変参考になりました。

Answer (score 6):

自分の理解を。

クラスベースのオブジェクト指向言語においては、設計図(クラス)に対する実態(インスタンス)があるので、インスタンスという言葉が使われている。

オブジェクト指向のオブジェクトとはもう少し広い概念で、オブジェクトそれぞれがメソッド(メッセージ)を受け取って特定の処理をする、そのパラダイムのプログラミングの登場人物。

なのでクラスベースではインスタンス=オブジェクトだが、その他のオブジェクト指向ではインスタンスという用語は本来の意味から考えれば使われるべきではない。

---

と思っていたのですが、ちょっと調べると javascript でも instanceof 演算とかありますね。。ただ、オブジェクトが定義されるにあたって、その原型(クラスやプロトタイプ)は必ずしも存在する必要はなく、やっぱり、インスタンス == 特定のクラスないしプロトタイプを実装・実現するオブジェクト が自分の理解です。

---

例えば具体的には、 OCaml はクラスがないオブジェクトを生成できたはず。

Comment: オイラが C++er な関係でクラスベースな OO しか頭に無かったのですが、確かにプロトタイプベースな OO では両者は違うものですね。

Answer (score 0):

なんとなくですが、

- インスタンスはメモリ上にある情報・実態。関数は含まない。現実に例えるとただ存在してるだけ（時間軸がない）。
- オブジェクトはインスタンス + クラスで定義された関数。現実に例えるとそこにあり他と干渉するもの（時間軸がある）。

なんかすごい厨二くさい…

Answer (score 0):

簡単に、

- インスタンス=実体、物。(例:人、車)
- オブジェクト=クラス、インスタンスをまとめた物、メモリに置かれているもの。
- クラス(質問には無いですが)=設計図

と考えればいいと思います。

Answer (score -1):

上手く書けませんが・・・
クラスはインスタンスではありませんが、クラスもインスタンスもオブジェクトです。